# Crear conteo para grilla

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Quiero armar una grilla donde se muestren la cantidad de registros x Mes de todo el año.

Como encabezado de tabla tendria el nombre de los typo de novedades.
Ejemplo:

- Vacaciones
- Inansistencia
- Llamados de atencion
- etc (ya que el administrador puede agregar mas tipos)

Y en las filas iria los meses

- Enero
- Febrero
- Marzo
- etc....

Actualmente estoy cotando los registros de cada mes de la siguiente manera:

```
public function scopeEmployeeGrillaYear($query,$employee_id,$month,$year)
{
    $records = $this->select(DB::raw('count(*) as type, type_new_id'))
                ->whereEmployee_id($employee_id)
                ->whereMonth('date_new',$month)
                ->whereYear('date_new',$year)
                ->groupBy('type_new_id')
                ->get();

    return $records;
}
```

Agrupo la cantidad de registro segun el tipo groupBy(type_new_id). Y en la vista lo muestro de la siguiente forma:

```
<table class="col-md-12 table table-hover table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
            <th>Meses</th>
            @foreach($types as $type)
            <th scope="col">{{$type->name}}</th>
            @endforeach
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Septiembre</td>
                @foreach($recordsSep as $record)
                <td>{{$record->type_new_id}}</td>
                @endforeach
                <td>Ver</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

El problema de esto es que cuando no tengo en un mes el tipo de registro que figura el encabezado necesito mostrar 0 , y en este caso directamente no lo muestra por lo que se corren las columnas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador

```
public function grilla($employee_id,$year)
{
    $employee = Employee::findOrFail($employee_id); // Busco empleado
    $types = TypeNew::orderBy('name')->get(); // Traigo los encabezados de la grilla
    $recordsSep = Record::EmployeeGrillaYear($employee_id,9,$year); // Filtro los registros segun el mes

    return view('rrhh.report.report-employee-year',compact('employee','year','types','recordsSep'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- En tu tbody deberias recorrer el array $types he ir haciendo un filter de tu array $recordsSep para mostrar los datos

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Septiembre</td>
        @foreach($types as $type)
            @php
                $count=0;
                $found=$recordsSep->firstWhere('type_new_id',$type->id);
                if($found){
                    $count=$found->type;
                }
            @endphp
            <td>{{$count}}</td>
        @endforeach
        <td>Ver</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Perfecto, Mil gracias !